# Grails import SpringSecurityUtils unresolve class

Tags: grails, spring-security

Using Grails 2.4.4. So I wanted to create a custom LoginController.groovy and I copied the file from an old project to the controller directory (no package). It can't seem to resolve the class for SpringSecurityUtils.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
```

One stackoverflow answer mentioned using, but this also did not work.

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils //Did not work
```

=> Groovy:unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

I do see the spring-securty-core.jar in the build path. 
Running >grails run-app from CLI also has the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Verify the package name again. Its

[`grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils`](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/java/grails/plugin/springsecurity/SpringSecurityUtils.java)

Notice `plugin` instead of `plugins` in package.

Comment: Yes that was it. 2 hours for one letter :)

Comment: It should not be 2 hours if an IDE is used. :)